# GDI+ C++; Why Image::Save returns InvalidParameter when using encoder parameters?

Tags: c++, gdi+

When I don't use `Gdiplus::EncoderParameters*`, image successfully saves. But when I get parameters from image, `Image::Save()` return `InvalidParameter` and saving fails. Why?

Code example:

```cpp
Bitmap* bmp = ...;   // it's jpeg image from file
const CLSID clsID = GetEncoderClsid(L"image/jpeg");

EncoderParameters* encodParams = NULL;
UINT size = bmp->GetEncoderParameterListSize(&clsID);
if (size > 0) {
    encodParams = (Gdiplus::EncoderParameters*)malloc(size);
    if (Gdiplus::Status::Ok == bmp->GetEncoderParameterList(&clsID, size, encodParams)){
            const WCHAR* dst = ...;
            bmp->Save(dst, &clsID, encodParams);
      }
}
```

Comment: `malloc` won't put anything in the memory it allocates, it will be filled with junk.

Comment: I put data to encoder parameters by calling the bmp->GetEncoderParameterList

Comment: That's not guaranteed to fill in everything.  You'll want to zero everything out before you make that call.

Comment: Maybe instead of calling those functions with `bmp->` you should use `Gdiplus::Image::`.